# error: unable to unlink old 'docker/dev/db/my.cnf': Device or resource busy

Tags: laravel, git, docker

I am running a project in [docker](/questions/tagged/docker).

I can not discard the file changes. I can not `git reset -- hard`. I can not `git pull`. I also have permissions.

Can someone help me how to discard change of `my.cnf` file and can `git pull`?

[image]

[image]

Note: I have permision to docker/dev/db/my.cnf file but it is not still allowing discrad the change and can not allow to git pull. I tried git reset --hard HEAD, but showing error message unable to reverse.

Comment: I have permision to docker/dev/db/my.cnf file but it is not still allowing discrad the change and can not allow to git pull. I tried git reset --hard HEAD, but showing error message unable to reverse.

Comment: Did you stop the container from running ? If you are using `docker-compose` a simple `docker-compose stop` will allow you to stop using the container, hence your DB container will stop using the file `my.cnf` so you will be able to delete it or do what you want with it...